# Generate a differences of a unique observations accross a date range

Tags: r

Ciao guys,

i have the following dataframe.

```
obj <- data.frame (occ= c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
Date = c("1990-01", "1990-01", "1990-01", "1990-01", "1990-02", "1990-02", "1990-02", "1990-02", "1990-03", "1990-03", "1990-03", "1990-03", "1990-04", "1990-04", "1990-04", "1990-04"),
                   emp_value = c(33, 0, 55, 44, 0, 50, 70, 80, 91, 32, 32, 22, 11, 31, 42, 51)
)
```

I would like to do the following:

I would like generate a variable which takes the difference in emp_value for every unique occupation (occ) between different dates.

My desired dataframe would be

```
obj <- data.frame (occ= c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
               Date = c("1990-01", "1990-01", "1990-01", "1990-01", "1990-02", "1990-02", "1990-02", "1990-02", "1990-03", "1990-03", "1990-03", "1990-03", "1990-04", "1990-04", "1990-04", "1990-04"),
               emp_value = c(33, 0, 55, 44, 0, 50, 70, 80, 91, 32, 32, 22, 11, 31, 42, 51), 
               emp_diff = c(0, 0, 0, 0, -33, 50, 15, 36, 91, -18, -38, -48, -69, -70, -1, 10)
```

)

Note that my real data frame consists of thousands of values and hundreds of different occupations. In addition, not every occupation appears within each date.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens, if one date is missing? Is you data.frame ordered by Date?

Comment: Yes it is ordered by date. Only occupations (variable occ) within a date can be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
obj %>%
  group_by(occ) %>%
  mutate(emp_diff = emp_value - lag(emp_value, default = 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your message! That was almost what I needed, I just had to replace lag(emp_diff, default = 0) by lag(emp_value , default = 0).
Thanks man!

Comment: Ah...my mistake.corrected it.

Comment: If a occurence is missing, this one takes the differences between  two consecutive dates. If one occurence is missing it subtractes for example `1900-01-01` and `1900-01-03`.